# Calculating stop light intervals based on current time.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for calculating when a light will change to green/how long it will stay green.

I have the following simplified example data:
Current time: AM 7:42:20　seconds(red)
Light turns green at 7:43:00 exactly.
Green light lasts 120 seconds, until 7:45

We then have a red light for 60 seconds until 7:45:59
Light then turns green again at 7:46.

In other words:
Green: 120 seconds
Red:60 seconds

While I(as a programmer) know I can calculate the time it will turn green in 24 hours and store it in an array, I am trying to solve problems more mathematically and efficiently.

How would a more mathematically inclined person calculate if the light was currently green or red at any time in the day knowing the length of the green and red light, and a base time at which it was calculated. Eg turned green at 7:43?

I have tried finding a pattern with modulo, and also tried just using the last digit and subtraction, but I am having trouble getting anything solid.

I am more interested in the thought process than the actual answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert all times to seconds and consider the quantity ..

$$\delta t \equiv (t-t_{ref}) \mod 180  $$

if $\delta t < 120$ then the light is green and will remain so for $(120-\delta t)$ seconds

otherwise the light is red and will remain so for $(180-\delta t)$ seconds

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you chose mod 180? I understand it is the total seconds, but how/what was the logic you used to decide 'we need to mod by 180 or it will not work?'

Comment: the repeating pattern is Green: 120 seconds Red:60 seconds which is 180 seconds long. Other correct solutions exist using different mods, but using 180 requires the simplest analysis